# ssl handshake failure with SSL routines:ssl3_finish_mac failure after openssl upgrade to 1.1.1c

Tags: c, openssl, sslhandshakeexception

SSL_connect() failed with reason SSL routines:ssl3_finish_mac failure

I have no idea about what will be root cause for this failure

It is working fine till openssl 1.1.0. after upgrading to 1.1.1c. this failure is observed